# CQRS mediator in Python

Tags: python, mediator

I've been studying the [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) pattern created by Gregory Young and have been trying to come up with some sort of library or set of classes I can reuse in other projects.

This is the mediator (bus) part which can be used in web apps, on controller classes, to push either **Commands** and **Queries** to respective handlers. This implementation is meant to be short and easy, so I don't try to do anything special with transports and just let everything happen in memory.

Also, because the CQRS pattern is commonly implemented with *Event Sourcing* I've added the possibility of publishing **Events** through this very same mediator.

`Immutable` and `Identifiable` are supporting classes used in the code, but I've excluded them here for brevity -- I hope their names will be self-describing.

I know some people who've seen [Jack Diederich's talk on Stopping Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) will consider it a sin to just have classes with `__init__`, but in my opinion it allows for better differentiation of message types.

Finally, I'll be posting a different ask for review on the event sourcing side in a bit.

Please review this code and let me know your options.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import uuid
from datetime import *
from . import Immutable, Identifiable, snake_case


class Message(Immutable, Identifiable):

    def __init__(self, id = None, correlation_id = None, sequence_no = None, version = None):
        Immutable.__init__(self)
        Identifiable.__init__(self)
        self.id = id or uuid.uuid1()
        self.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
        self.correlation_id = correlation_id
        self.sequence_no = sequence_no
        self.version = version


class Command(Message):

    def __init__(self):
        Message.__init__(self)


class Query(Message):

    def __init__(self):
        Message.__init__(self)


class Event(Message):

    def __init__(self):
        Message.__init__(self)


def get_conventioned_message_type(message):
    return snake_case(message.__class__.__name__)


class MessageHandler(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def handle(self, message):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def can_handle(self, message):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ConventionBasedMessageHandler(MessageHandler):
    """Base class for Messages Handlers which follows the convention that for
    each kind of message that they can handle they have a method called
    "handle_<message type in snake case>"
    """

    def handle(self, message):
        method = self._get_handle_method(message)
        if method:
            return method(message)

    def can_handle(self, message):
        if isinstance(message, str):
            method = getattr(self, 'handle_' + message)
            return method != None and callable(method)
        return self._get_handle_method(message) != None

    def _get_handle_method_name(self, message):
        return 'handle_' +  get_conventioned_message_type(message)

    def _get_handle_method(self, message):
        try:
            method = getattr(self, self._get_handle_method_name(message), None)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
        else:
            if callable(method):
                return method
            else:
                return None


class ConventionBasedMessageBus(object):
    """
    A mediator to encapsulate request/response and publishing interaction patterns
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._handlers = {}

    def subscribe(self, message, handler):
        message_name = snake_case(message.__name__)
        if not (message_name.endswith('command') or message_name.endswith('event') or message_name.endswith('query')):
            raise ValueError('Message type must follow convention of ending name with "Event" or "Command" or "Query"!')

        if not issubclass(message, Message):
            raise ValueError('message must be of type Message')

        if not isinstance(handler, ConventionBasedMessageHandler):
            raise ValueError('handler must be of type ConventionBasedMessageHandler')

        if not handler.can_handle(message_name):
            raise ValueError('handler must be able to handle given message type')

        if not self._handlers.get(message_name):
            self._handlers[message_name] = []

        if (message_name.endswith('command') or message_name.endswith('query')) and len(self._handlers.get(message_name)) != 0:
            raise MultipleMessageHandlersRegistered("Command handler for %s already registered" % (message_name))

        self._handlers[message_name].append(handler)

    def publish(self, message):
        """ Send a message to multiple handlers"""
        if not isinstance(message, Event):
            raise ValueError('message must be of type Event')

        message_name = snake_case(message.__class__.__name__)

        if not self._handlers.get(message_name):
            self._handlers[message_name] = []

        for handler in self._handlers[message_name]:
            handler.handle(event)

    def send(self, message):
        """Sends a message to a single handler"""
        if not isinstance(message, (Query, Command)):
            raise ValueError('message must be of type Query or Command')

        message_name = snake_case(message.__class__.__name__)

        if not self._handlers.get(message_name):
            raise NoMessageHandlersRegistered("no registered handler for messages of type: %s." % (message_name))

        rv = self._handlers[message_name][0].handle(message)
        if isinstance(message, Query):
            return rv

Mediator = ConventionBasedMessageBus

class MultipleMessageHandlersRegistered(Exception):
    pass

class NoMessageHandlersRegistered(Exception):
    pass

class ConflictingCommandException(Exception):
    pass

class CommandValidationException(Exception):
    pass
```

How I use this class is perhaps better explained by the test cases I apply to it:

```
class MediatorTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    class InvalidMessage(Message):
        pass

    class SampleQuery(Query):
        pass

    class SampleCommand(Command):
        pass

    class SampleEvent(Event):
        def get_event_source_id(self):
            pass

    class SampleHandler(ConventionBasedMessageHandler):

        def handle_sample_event(self, event):
            return 1

        def handle_sample_query(self, query):
            return 1

        def handle_sample_command(self, command):
            return 1

    def setUp(self):
        self.mediator = Mediator()

    def test_fails_when_message_doest_follow_convention(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.InvalidMessage, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())

    def test_only_a_single_handler_can_subcribe_to_query(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())
            self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())

    def test_only_a_single_handler_can_subcribe_to_command(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleCommand, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())
            self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleCommand, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())

    def test_multiple_handlers_can_subcribe_to_events(self):
        self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleEvent, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())
        self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleEvent, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())

    def test_sending_message_with_no_registered_handlers_fails_for_commands_and_queries(self):
        query = MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery()
        command = MediatorTestCase.SampleCommand()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.send(command)
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.send(query)

    def test_sending_event_fails(self):
        event = MediatorTestCase.SampleEvent()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.send(event)

    def test_publishing_commands_or_queries_fails(self):
        query = MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery()
        command = MediatorTestCase.SampleCommand()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.publish(command)
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.mediator.publish(query)

    def test_sending_message_with_no_registered_handlers_passes_for_events(self):
        self.mediator.publish(MediatorTestCase.SampleEvent())

    def test_publishing_events_and_sending_commmands_doesnt_return_anything(self):
        query = MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery()
        command = MediatorTestCase.SampleCommand()
        event = MediatorTestCase.SampleEvent()
        self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleCommand, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())
        self.assertIsNone( self.mediator.publish(event) )
        self.assertIsNone( self.mediator.send(command) )

    def test_sending_queries_returns_something(self):
        query = MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery()
        self.mediator.subscribe(MediatorTestCase.SampleQuery, MediatorTestCase.SampleHandler())
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.mediator.send(query))
        self.assertEquals(1, self.mediator.send(query))
```